# Inkscape line alway visible

Tags: inkscape

I use Inkscape 92.2.
Windows 7 x64.

How to display always line, event the size is set to 0,002mm.
If the line is big, i will see line, i won't if line is small.

How to display always line, event the size is set to 0,002mm.
If the line is big, i will see line, i won't if line is small.

I have rectangle, 2m big with line set to 0,002mm, and i can't see the rectangle

How to display the line regardless the line size is set?

Comment: This is somewhat off topic, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The line you are trying to make is about the size of a single bacterium. Make the line bigger until you can see it.